# Excluir uma macro usando outra

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Como programar uma macro para excluir outra?
Seria algo parecido, como quando, eu preciso chamar?
Ex.:

```
Sub callmacro()
Call macro1
End sub
```

E, melhor ainda, se eu quiser programa-la para se auto excluir?

Ex.:

```
Sub macro1()

Dim i as...

For i = 0 to...
...
Next

'e aqui, depois de uma serie de comandos, a macro se auto excluiria.'

End sub
```

Comment: A pergunta é interessante. Mas ai vem a inevitável dúvida: há algum motivo pra você querer remover a macro?

Comment: Com certeza. A primeira indagaçao acredito que seja comum. Se eu tiver um planilha com comandos extensos e muito dinamica. A segunda talvez pareça inusitada, mas é uma possibilidade.

Comment: O meu ponto é: por que você precisaria excluir uma macro existente (seja isso feito por ela mesma ou por outra macro)? Não sei se é possível (imagino que seja, sem ser necessariamente trivial), mas não vejo muito propósito nisso. Uma planilha com comandos extensos foi - em teoria - planejada assim. Ninguém iria gastar tempo construindo um "comando" que não fosse necessário. Assim, eu queria saber se o seu problema na verdade não é outro (e as vezes tem solução diferente).

Comment: Luiz entendo muito bem a sua colocaçao. Mas a minha pergunta é direta. Se eu for debater as aplicaçoes isso estaria fugindo do escopo desta comunidade( que ja aconteceu, ja levei tanta porrada e negativaçao, nem quero criar mais perguntas com extensoes).

Comment: Mas so o exemplificar, bem simples. Uma macro roda automaticamente ao abrir a planilha, depois de um tempo, armazenando dados ou gerando mais informaçoes, gostaria que a rotina do workbook open mudasse. No minimo teria que modifica la ou no caso, apagal e inserir outra.

Comment: Eu entendo o seu medo. Ainda assim, há inúmeras outras formas de você resolver a parte "[...] depois de um tempo, armazenando dados ou gerando mais informaçoes, gostaria que a rotina do workbook open mudasse." *sem precisar remover nada*. Mas, realmente, a sua pergunta é bem direta. Eu só estava tentando ajudar prevendo que talvez a sua escolha de abordagem não seja a melhor. Eu vou apagar os comentários, então, ok? Boa sorte. :)

Comment: Nao precisa apagar. Na verdade é ate esclarecedor. Nao estou recusando criticas.

Comment: Ok, sem problemas. :)

Comment: Um problema que venho enfrentando aqui é que as vezes acho muitos olham a pergunta e provavelmente interpretam como a de um iniciante, e parecem ignorar. Nem recebo respostas, muito menos um bom questionamento como o seu. Simplesmente sou negativado, ou por nao terem a resposta, por achar facil de mais eu acho, ou por nao saberem mesmo e acharem desnecessaria.

Comment: Acredite: [não](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/minhas-perguntas-s%C3%A3o-t%C3%A3o-ruins-assim) acontece [só](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4829/eu-n%C3%A3o-sei-perguntar-e-voc%C3%AA) com [você](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4800/o-que-est%C3%A1-acontecendo-com-os-votos-negativos). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É possível fazer o que você quer, mas pra isso funcionar *o usuário* (sim, ele mesmo!) precisa alterar a configuração do Excel dele para indicar que confia em macros que fazem acesso ao modelo de objetos **do projeto** VBA (essa opção não é marcada por padrão porque assim evita vírus de macro).

A forma de dar esse acesso depende da versão do Excel. No Office 2010 (que é o que eu tenho aqui), o usuário deve:

1 - Selecionar o item "Opções" no menu "Arquivo".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Selecionar a opção "Central de Confiabilidade" e então clicar no botão "Configurações da Central de Confiabilidade..."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 - Selecionar a opção "Configurações de Macro" e então marcar a opção "Confiar no acesso ao modelo de objeto do projeto do VBA"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo isso sido configurado, o código a seguir funciona:

```
Sub RemoveEuMesmo()

    On Error Resume Next

    Set oModulo = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Módulo1")

    If Not oModulo Is Nothing Then

        oModulo.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, oModulo.CodeModule.CountOfLines

        lin = "' Código removido automaticamente em " + Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss")
        oModulo.CodeModule.AddFromString lin

    End If

End Sub
```

Esse código é só de exemplo. Eu suponho que ele está no módulo de nome "Módulo1", e que é a única sub nesse módulo, e por isso removo todas as linhas de `1` a `oModulo.CodeModule.CountOfLines`. Se você quiser remover um trecho específico, você vai ter que saber *de antemão* quais são as linhas a serem removidas. Talvez tenha métodos para procurar (via uma espécie de reflexão) por uma sub com o nome dado, mas não procurei por detalhes e acho pouco provável que o VBA tenha esse nível de complexidade.

Ah, no exemplo, as linhas não são só removidas, eu deixo um comentário no lugar (achei que era legal a ilustração de que você também pode criar novo código diretamente em VBA).

> Atenção: Como eu menciono em comentários, essa abordagem não é a ideal
>   pra fazer o que eu entendi que vc precisa. Para ter um código que se
>   adapta ao volume de dados (talvez ao ponto de nunca mais ser
>   executado), requer apenas um `if`. O código pode permanecer ali, sem
>   nunca mais executar. Entende? A abordagem da remoção pode parecer uma boa
>   sacada (algo "*clever*"), mas ela requer configurações especiais que
>   podem te trazer problemas. Primeiramente, ela pode abrir brechas para
>   códigos maliciosos realmente serem executados no Excel do seu
>   cliente/usuário. Em segundo lugar, ela vai claramente gerar pra você
>   muitas dificuldades de manutenção do ambiente, pois se a configuração
>   não estiver habilitada o código simplesmente não vai funcionar **sem
>   gerar qualquer mensagem de erro!** Além disso, certos usuários podem
>   ter uma péssima percepção da qualidade do seu produto, se você pedir
>   pra eles habilitarem algo que é, digamos, perigoso.

Comment: Massa luiz. Se eu tivesse mais pontos lhe daria uma recompensa. Agradeço!

Comment: Obrigado. Fico feliz que gostou. Só que eu adicionei uma observação importante no final. Insisto que esse não é o melhor caminho. Mas, ai é com vc. Boa sorte! :)

Comment: Deixe comigo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Tambem Achei desta forma:

```
Sub DeleteModule()
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBproject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Set VBProj = activeworkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponent("Module1")
VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
End sub
```

Funciona tambem.

Comment: Verdade, bem lembrado. A diferença importante é que nesse exemplo você literalmente remove o módulo (com tudo dentro). Na solução da minha resposta o módulo continua lá e você tem controle exato sobre as linhas de código a serem removidas. :) Se quiser, pode editar a resposta pra incluir essa diferença nela (ai eu apago do comentário).