# Como criar eventos dinamicamente no VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, variáveis, eventos

O código abaixo cria Labels dinamicamente e agora **preciso controlar a ação do mouse** (evento "Click") sobre cada Label.

Por exemplo, passar a fonte do texto ("Caption") para **negrito** se estiver *regular* (não negritado).

**Há Como criar o evento "Click" e controlá-lo individualmente para cada Label neste caso?**

```
Private Sub CriaLabels(ByVal QuantidadeDeLabels As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim NewLabel(QuantidadeDeLabels-1) As Object

    For i = 0 To QuantidadeDeLabels-1

        Set NewLabel(i) = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

        With NewLabel(i)
            .Caption = "NewLabel" & i
            .Top = 50 * i
            .Left = 50
        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há algumas alternativas. Você pode tentar criar dinamicamente uma nova função de tratamento de click para cada label, utilizando o formato `<nome do controle>_Click()`, mas pra isso você precisará:

1 - Definir o nome dos controles na chamada de `Me.Controls.Add` (é mais um parâmetro após o progID da classe). Como o código vai precisar referenciar o objeto pelo nome, não basta só definir o "caption". O código abaixo faz essa definição de nome (apesar de ele não realmente precisar).

2 - Acessar o projeto do VBA para inserir as linhas de código manualmente.

Para fazer o item 2, é só olhar [esta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113795/73) aqui no SOPT. O exemplo lá insere um comentário, e você vai ter que inserir **todo** o código da(s) sua(s) função(ões).

> Vale notar que essa abordagem tem sérios(as) problemas/dificuldades.
>   Primeiramente, você vai ter que escrever o cóigo da função que vai ser
>   chamada no evento de clique dentro de outro código, tornando-o menos
>   legível e mais difícil de manter. Em segundo lugar, isso altera o
>   projeto VBA, de forma que vc vai precisar salvar o arquivo Excel a
>   cada execução. Em terceiro lugar, vai ficar difícil remover labels
>   porque você vai ter que procurar no código pelo nome exato da função,
>   achar o `end sub` exato dela para remover, etc. E finalmente (e
>   principalmente), isso requer a habilitação de uma configuração que
>   gera potencial problema de segurança (leia mais na resposta
>   referenciada).

Uma alternativa melhor (cuja fonte original é [esta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10224992/2896619)) é construir uma classe (um módulo de classe, pra ser mais exato) e fazer ela tratar **todos** os eventos de clique para todos os labels. Faça assim:

1 - Crie um módulo de classe com qualquer nome que desejar (no meu exemplo, eu chamei de `LabelHandler`).

2 - Nele, coloque o seguinte código:

```
Public WithEvents Ctrl As MSForms.Label

Private Sub Ctrl_Click()

    MsgBox "Você clicou no label de nome " & Ctrl.Name

End Sub
```

Esse código simplesmente declara uma propriedade/atributo da classe chamado `Ctrl` (novamente, chame como mais bem entender - só lembre-se de alterar a função de tratamento do click de forma apropriada: `<nome da propriedade>_Click()`) e implementa o *código genérico* para tratar o click no objeto definido naquela propriedade.

3 - No seu código original, mova a matriz de controles (labels) **para fora** do escopo da sua função. Ela precisa estar fora do escopo porque precisa continuar existindo depois que a função terminar. Além disso, faça essa matriz guardar instâncias da nova classe que criou (`LabelHandler`, no meu exemplo) ao invés de diretamente do Label criado.

4 - Por fim, adicione o controle (label) criado à propriedade da nova classe de tratamento. Eis o código:

```
Dim Labels() As New LabelHandler

Private Sub CriaLabels(ByVal QuantidadeDeLabels As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Label As Control

    ReDim Labels(0 To QuantidadeDeLabels - 1)

    For i = 0 To QuantidadeDeLabels - 1

        Set Label = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "NewLabel" & i)

        With Label
          .Caption = "NewLabel" & i
          .Top = 50 * i
          .Left = 50
        End With

        Set Labels(i).Ctrl = Label

    Next i

End Sub
```

Esse código gera o seguinte resultado (para um teste criando 4 labels - o botão de título "Teste" foi somente utilizado para invocar `CriaLabels 4`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que o código genérico executado na classe `LabelHandler` pode tratar diferenças com base no objeto clicado verificando o nome dele, por exemplo.

> **Nota Final**: No futuro, procure identar o código. Facilita a sua própria leitura e manutenção, e também de quem vai tentar te ajudar
>   por aqui.

Comment: Excelente resposta!!

Comment: Excelente Luiz, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado! Vou ajeitar o código.