# Capturar evento click checkbox dinâmico

Tags: vba

Criei uma lista de CheckBox conforme cada categoria é inserida na base de dados. Porém, não estou conseguindo capturar o evento click desses CheckBox criados dinamicamente. Alguém sabe onde está o erro?

```
Public Sub CarregarCheckBoxCategoria(Categoria As String)
Dim Cont As Integer

    Set chkCheckBox = frmProdutos.Frame3.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "NovoCheckBox", True)

    PositionTop = PositionTop + 12

    With chkCheckBox
        .Name = RemoverCaracter(Categoria)
        .Caption = Categoria
        .Width = 72
        .Height = 18
        .Top = .Top + PositionTop
        .Left = 186
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub NovoCheckBox_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    MsgBox "CheckBox has selected"
Else
    MsgBox "CheckBox has not selected"
End If
End Sub
```

Alterei o código acima, porém, só o último checkbox executa o evento Click. Segue o meu código:

**UserForm**

```
Public Sub CarregarCheckBoxCategoria(Categoria As String)
Dim CheckBox As Control

ReDim CheckBoxs(iChk)


    Set CheckBox = frmProdutos.Frame3.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "NovoCheckBox", True)


    PositionTop = PositionTop + 12

    With CheckBox
        .Name = RemoverCaracter(Categoria)
        .Caption = Categoria
        .Width = 72
        .Height = 18
        .Top = .Top + PositionTop
        .Left = 186
    End With

    Set CheckBoxs(iChk).Ctrl = CheckBox

    iChk = iChk + 1
End Sub
```

**Módulo**

```
Option Explicit

Public CheckBoxs() As New CheckBoxHandler
Public iChk As Integer
Public PositionTop As Integer

Private Conn As ADODB.Connection
Private rst As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub ExtrairCategoria()
iChk = 0

Dim strQuery As String
strQuery = "SELECT CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories ORDER BY CategoryName"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open strQuery, Conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic

frmProdutos.cmbCategoria.Clear

Do While Not rst.EOF()
    frmProdutos.cmbCategoria.AddItem rst!CategoryName

    Call frmProdutos.CarregarCheckBoxCategoria(rst!CategoryName)

    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Na Classe CheckBoxHandler**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Ctrl As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub Ctrl_Click()

    MsgBox "Você clicou no CheckBox de nome " & Ctrl.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão de que o seu `ReDim` tá errado. Compare no meu código original [lá na outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130365/73). Ele usa o Redim apenas para definir o tamanho final do array. No seu caso, vc tá tentando fazer ele crescer dinamicamente (a cada chamada). Nesse caso, o array perde todo o conteúdo já existente. Vc devia ter usado o `Preserve` na chamada do `ReDim` (dá uma olhada [na documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)).

Comment: Outra coisa que parece errada é que o `ReDim` espera os índices ou o tamanho do array. Como vc usa o tamanho, acho que deveria ser `iChk+1` (senão ele vai sempre ter um a menos do que o necessário).

Comment: Luiz, eu incluí o preserve e funcionou perfeitamente. Vou analisar a outra sugestão sobre o tamanho para ver se essa alteração vai influenciar em algo. Mas a primeira sugestão já resolvei o meu problema. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kelly, veja neste **link** que a forma que fez não é a adequada.

[Como criar eventos dinamicamente no VBA?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130321/como-criar-eventos-dinamicamente-no-vba)

Como verá, a sua rotina **"NovoCheckBox_Click**" deve fazer parte de um "**módulo de classe**".

Veja na resposta do **Luiz Vieira** todo o passo do que e como deve fazer, há inclusive o exemplo de código para tanto. Eu usei exatamente da forma descrita por ele e funcionou perfeitamente.

Apesar de ser outra questão, você deve criar todos de uma vez inicialmente, em um **For Next**, e nāo pontualmente, desta forma resolve pois você terá obrigatoriamente que **definir ou calcular a quantidade de objetos dinâmicos a serem criados** para iniciar o **For Next**.

Para esta mesma quantidade de cada grupo de objetos, se for trabalhar com grupos, eliminando o grupo anterior para processar o novo grupo (que pode ter um tamanho menor de itens ou maior, por exemplo) o **Redim** será acionado **uma unica vez por grupo** com esta mesma quantidade (ou ela menos um se iniciar do índice zero para controlar desde o zero e não desde o um).

Pode fazer assim que funcionará.

Comment: Leo, tentei adaptar o exemplo que me sugeriu ao meu código. Ele agora identifica o click, mas apenas do último checkbox. Vou editar o meu código para você dar uma olhada onde estou errando.

Comment: Kelly, por favor, não sei se terei tempo agora, sugiro que crie nova questão, pois a solução da primeira foi encaminhada e sua dúvida agora é outra, incluindo novas partes de código. Mais tarde voltarei a analisar se não der tempo agora.

Comment: Correto, porém esta questão é DUPLICADA, consulte o link, a resposta dada pelo Luiz Vieira é extensa e completa, portanto, não era o caso de repetir o que já foi respondido. Veja também os comentários. Eu auxiliei com a resposta exatamente no que foi questionado: ONDE ESTÁ O ERRO? E eu apontei com precisão.

Comment: Não é uma questão de quem leva os créditos. Aqui no site, as perguntas não são um diálogo, não é para evoluírem conforme a dúvida vai mudando. Quando isso acontece, elas passam a ser cada vez menos úteis a outras pessoas.

Comment: Concordo, alterar uma pergunta respondida gerando outra, confunde quem esta pesquisando e faz perder o sentido das resposta  dadas, alem de desmotivar os que se dedicaram a responder inicialmente. Vou complementar minha resposta de forma a atender as duas questões   feitas aqui.

Comment: Respondidas as duas questoes.

Comment: Leo, já resolvi o problema. Era só a falta do PRESERVE. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Ok, o efeito é o mesmo, pois em ambos os casos a nova matriz a ser tratada é redimensionada, no meu caso ao se criar a matriz zerando seus valores a cada novo grupo gerado (a matriz é criada integralmente), no seu caso "redimencionando" pontualmente a matriz, mas preservando os valores anteriores (passo a passo). Nos dois casos a matriz resultante atende às necessidades de processamento.