# Realizar ação para cada linha em uma busca SQL - VB

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, visual-studio, visual-basic-6

gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar com a seguinte questão.

Em um código VB, quero realizar a busca de produtos em uma tabela SQL. Pra cada produto encontrado eu gostaria de adicionar um botão em um painel.

Se isso não for possível, eu consigo "personalizar" um datagrid(?) tipo o exemplo abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Agradeço desde já a atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem uma solução em VBA que adaptei abaixo e que pode ser adaptada também para o teu caso, a referência vem de uma pergunta que fiz e foi respondida pelo Luiz Vieira, veja no link abaixo.

[Como criar eventos dinamicamente no VBA/Excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130321/como-criar-eventos-dinamicamente-no-vba)

A ideia é criar dinamicamente um botão para cada imagem ou posição no 'grid', que irá depender de quantos resultados irá encontrar em cada busca.

Primeiro crie um **módulo de classe** que nomeei de DynamicCommandButton (os códigos abaixo estão feitos para o VBA do Excel)

```
Public WithEvents CommandButtonClick As msforms.CommandButton
'Declaração da propriedade/atributo da classe

Private Sub CommandButtonClick_Click()
'Será a propriedade/atributo de cada CommandButton criado
'Neste caso está associado ao evento Click

    ActionCommanButton CommandButtonClick.Name
    'Procedure que deseja executar para o botão acionado

End Sub

Private Sub ActionCommanButton(ButtonName As String)

    Beep

    MsgBox "Você clicou no Botão " & ButtonName & "!"

End Sub
```

**No formulário coloque assim**:

```
Dim CommandButtons() As New DynamicCommandButton
'O módulo de Classe que contém o evento Click para o CommadButton

Private Sub CreateCommandButtons(ByVal NumberOfCommandButtons As Integer)
'Esta procedure cria quantos botões desejar

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim NewButton As Control

    ReDim CommandButtons(0 To NumberOfCommandButtons - 1)

    For i = 0 To NumberOfCommandButtons - 1

        Set NewButton = Me.Controls.Add( _
          "Forms.CommandButton.1", _
          "NewButton" & i)

        With NewButton
          .Caption = "NewButton" & i
          .Top = 50 * i + 30
          .Left = 30
        End With

        Set CommandButtons(i).CommandButtonClick = NewButton

    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    CreateCommandButtons 4

End Sub
```

**Observação:** você deverá adaptar esta procedure para passar a posição X e Y de cada botão que deseja criar por trabalhar em 'grid', aqui no caso ele cria um botão abaixo do outro. Neste exemplo solicitei 4 botões para serem criados.

**Este é o resultado**:

[image: Resultado]

Portanto, basta ter as coordenadas X e Y de cada posição a colocar o botão e adaptar a rotina para criá-los nestas posições.

Comment: Obrigado Leo! Desculpa pela demora, alguns imprevistos me impossibilitaram de responder, perdão.  Seu código me ajudou e consegui realizar oq precisava graças a sua ajuda, Obrigado!

Comment: De nada amigo, excelente que tenha te ajudado! Você é iniciante aqui no SOPT, leia a Ajuda, veja que pode votar nas perguntas e respostas, isso ajuda a comunidade a avaliar a importância delas.